# Enviar datos a base de datos online

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

tengo una base de datos local y quiero enviar los datos de esta a una base de datos online, he creado el siguiente código en el que pretendo enviar a la base de datos online el nombre, la fecha, la id y la ubicación de todos los registros que tengan como code 'prueba'. Pero al ejecutarlo obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo hacer que funcione?

```
<?php
//LOCAL

$servername1 = "localhost";
$database1 = "ianseo";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
// Crear conexion
$conn1 = mysqli_connect($servername1, $username1, $password1, $database1);
// Verificar conexion
if (!$conn1) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Conexion correcta con el servidor local. - ";


 $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn1,"SELECT * FROM tournament WHERE code = 'prueba'") or die ("Error: $sql1");
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$nombre = $mostrar['ToName'];
$ID = $mostrar['ToCode'];
$Fecha= $mostrar['ToWhenFrom'];
$Ubicacion = $mostrar['ToWhere'];




//SERVER

$servername = "s";
$database = "d";
$username = "u";
$password = "p";
// Crear conexion
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
//Verificar conexion
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Conexion correcta con el servidor online. - ";

foreach($mostrar as $campo=>$r)
    mysqli_query($conn,"
        INSERT INTO comp (nombre, ID, Ubicacion, Fecha)
            VALUES ('".$r['nombre']."', '".$r['code']."', '".$r['ToWhere']."', '".$r['ToWhenFrom']."')
    ");

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Fijate que en la parte superior los campos los son `toName`, `toCode` y en la parte de abajo tienes otro nombre.

Comment: Lo he corregido pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error

Comment: Las primeros errores dicen que no existen esos nombres, estás seguro que así se llaman los nombres de los campos en la base de datos.

Comment: Si, se llamam así los campos de la base de datos

Comment: Si ya corrigio el error que menciona Juan Millan. Deberian aparecer solo 4 (Notice). {Los primeros 4} quieren decir que el indice que esta tratando de acceder no ha sido definido, por cuanto no existe. Puede hacer un print_r de $mostrar ?

Comment: Me salen solo los 4 primeros, pero en la base de datos sí tengo 4 campos con esos nombres y contienen datos, por tanto no comprende el error